# SharePoint Permissions - User w/ Full Control cannot create page

Tags: sharepoint-2007, permissions

I have two users who have **Full Control** permissions to their department sub-site on SharePoint.  They also have **Full Control** to the Pages document library.  The Pages doc library has distinct permission from the site itself, but those two users have **Full Control** on both as mentioned.

When they try to create a New Page it gives them an "`Access Denied`" error.  I can duplicate this problem with my non-admin account as well.

What am I missing to give these users the ability to create new pages on their site?

Comment: I've had this problem before, but it was on a top level site.
I had to add the users to Site Collection Administrators so they would be able to edit(the main page).  This may help, but it may give them more access than needed

Comment: The pages are being created in that library? They are being used by the whole site though? Seems that the site wants to enforce the lower of permissions because it is confused. Can they create normal documents or drag doc pages into the library with the file explorer?

Comment: I have same problem on my SP2013 here. Only site collection admin (not even full control users) can create new page under Pages doc library.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the user has been granted enough rights to create pages at site level in the first place but is still unable to do so even with Full Control, then there is a high possibility that the user ***DOES NOT*** have ***READ*** access to the ***Master Pages and page layouts*** library. Check the library permissions at the root site collection and grant them the specified permission level accordingly.

Hope that helps.

This is a applicable to SP10 and SP13

Thanks

Ismail

Comment: This advice is applicable for SharePoint 2007 too (which we are still using).

Comment: You are a genius!

Answer (score 1):

It could also be `TaxonomyHiddenList`.
You must paste it into your browser - you cannot navigate to it and it is at the site collection level..

```
http://yoursite/yoursitecollection/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList
```

**List Menu -> List Settings -> Permissions for this list -> Grant Permissions**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possibly to do with the Web Feature called "Content Organiser" which is enabled and not used. If it is activated, de-activate it and test again. This feature will affect document libraries, not lists.